# Control mechanisms on banks' total income

Tags: banking, online-banking

What standard or rule controls total money transactions in a bank (especially internet banks) so that they don't create money for themselves?

As I understand it, banks can create money as they loan.  So what if some manager decides to create free money for himself?

Comment: What do you mean "create money as they loan"?

Comment: This appears to conflate the idea that bank loans increase the "money supply" as a macroeconomic concept, with "creating free money".  Read the examples under section "M1" at this Wikipedia article, and adjust the question if this does not clarify it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_supply

Comment: Questions about economics should be asked at http://economics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you a manager at a bank?

Comment: No, I am consultant in IT field, totally irrelevant. I just wanted to know. @Nuwin

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Thanks, I didn't choose the place so well. I will remember.

Answer (score 2):

Banks are audited, for obvious reasons. Their software is carefully audited and protected, also for obvious reasons. A branch manager can't normally bypass those without getting caught quite quickly. He might be able to issue himself a loan -- but it will have to be a loan that at least appears to conform to the bank's standards, and he'll have to pay it off just like any other loan.

Comment: Can you add a reference?